# C# GetHashCode() High Performance Hashing Algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, object, gethashcode, hashalgorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

This is known to us that if we override the `Equals` method of `Object` in our custom types, we should also override and provide an implementation of `GetHashCode` method to support generating unique hash codes for use in support of `Hashtable` and `Dictionary` collection classes and may be other classes.

This mandates our implementation of the hashing algorithm used inside our `overriden` `GetHashCode` method is optimal and accurate i.e. it generates a unique hash of the type and also does that as quickly as possible to improve performance of application that uses our type.

My question is to ***which hashing algorithms*** are accurate and give optimal performance when used in `GetHashCode` implementation? Or, should we only use the base type's `GetHashCode` implementation? I would like to know this answer for both `value types` and `reference types`..

Edit: Here's an example of a class below on why I would need to override `Equals`:

```
public class Laptop : LaptopBase
{
    public readonly string Make;
    public readonly string ProcessorArch;
    public readonly int MemorySupported;
    public readonly int HardDiskGBSupported;
    public readonly Color ColorName;

    public Laptop(make, procArch, memorySupp, hdGB, color)
    {
        Make = make;
        ProcessorArch = procArch;
        MemorySupported = memorySupp;
        HardDiskGBSupported = hdGB;
        ColorName = color;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to return true for 2 Laptop instances that have all the above defined fields matching with each other so that requires to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method and also another requirement as you can see is that this is a derived class and may be re-used further and support a number of methods; and thus, cannot be made a value type (struct). I tried with 2 instances of above type with all matching instance fields and if I use the base implementation of `Equals` - it returns `false` where I want it to be `true`..
**How would I support such a scenario?**

Comment: Hashes arent required to be unique just that if a.Equals(b) then a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()

Comment: This has been asked many times, search. And the best advice is probably: do not override Equals et al.

Comment: You are unlikely to receive a generic answer to what the "optimal" hash function would look like. It very much depends on your definition of equality and what your object looks like in general. I would suggest you look around the site to see how others have implemented `GetHashCode` and then ask a specific question to a particular use case.

Comment: @BrokenGlass I have edited and provided a use case..I would also suggest to wait for a considerable time before closing the questions and give time to edit the questions...Thanks

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have added a code scenario and would like this question to be reopened and reexamined for answers and thoughts..

Comment: You've posted a mutable class with _public fields_ and without a proper context for Equals(). Not good enough. If that's the real class, don't override.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thats just a sample class to demo the scenario, in real case it would be an immutable class with read-only fields and constructor initialization..

Comment: @pickles I suppose the `GetHashCode` implementation of `Object` always produces a unique hashcode for the current AppDomain

Comment: No, it should not be unique... in GetHashCode() you could just return your [laptop_model_name].GetHashCode() and it will be enough. Equals could be implemented just as you said(plus it should check [laptom_model_name])

Comment: @CSharpVJ, hash codes are not guaranteed unique at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type it is implemented on, but it should give good dispersion of values and it is NOT a must for GetHashCode() to return a unique values. It should base on those fields that are used in your Equals implementation and those fields should be immutable. So requirements for Equals/GetHashCode are the same for structs and classes.

And as Henk said, it is better to not override Equals/GetHashCode at all...